# Apache Kafka File Pulse connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i am trying to read data from a binary file (tdms) row by row and transfer it using kafka.

my config looks like this

```
        "connector.class":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector",
    "fs.listing.class":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.LocalFSDirectoryListing",
    "fs.listing.directory.path":"C:/test",
     "fs.scan.interval.ms":"10000",
    "topic":"ui",
    "internal.kafka.reporter.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "transforms": "ExtractMessageToValue",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "transforms.ExtractMessageToValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.ExtractMessageToValue.field": "message",
    "tasks.reader.class":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.LocalRowFileInputReader",
    "fs.cleanup.policy.class":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.LogCleanupPolicy",
    "fs.scanner.class":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.scanner.local.LocalFSDirectoryWalker",        
    "tasks.file.status.storage.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "read.max.wait.ms":"5000",
    "allow.tasks.reconfiguration.after.timeout.ms":"1600",
    "offset.strategy":"name",
    "filters":"ConvertFilter",
    "filters.ConvertFilter.type":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.ConvertFilter",
    "filters.ConvertFilter.field":"message",
    "filters.ConvertFilter.to":"BYTES"
```

Currently the data is not read as bytes but as string from the file and then converted to bytes.
This leads to the problem that the file has some errors after the transfer and can not be opened anymore.

How can I define in the config that the  File Pulse connector reads the data directly as bytes from the file?

Comment: Last I checked, that connector cannot read binary data, only line-delimited text. Look at the source code on Github

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for replying. Do you know an other connector that can read a binary file row by row (constantly)?

Comment: I don't. Plus, binary data typically isn't line delimited. You could try forking this project https://github.com/C0urante/kafka-connect-sound/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/c0urante/kafka/connect/sound/MicrophoneSourceTask.java#L66